# What's the checksum algorithm for this? Please help to reverse engineer the algorithm

Tags: checksum

We are trying to make a gadget to interface with Sirius SXV300 module. We are now try to figure out it's communication checksum algorithm. Below are some data in hex strings. Our understanding is that 'DE C6' marks the start of each frame, and the last two bytes of each frame are checksum. We could only find their old version of protocol, and it says the checksum is "the 2’s-complement (negative) of the sum of all bytes from SYNC up to and including all bytes in the PAYLOAD, prior to byte stuffing". However, it seems that the new protocol uses different algorithm now. Here is the link to the old protocl: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mtpk3n5vcvaxlfg/Sirius%20RS232%20protocol.pdf?dl=0

`DE C6 22 01 00 04 40 A0 0F 0C DF C4
DE C6 23 01 00 04 40 A0 10 0D 00 CA
DE C6 25 01 00 05 43 00 12 01 22 8E 4C
DE C6 26 01 00 05 43 00 13 01 33 83 59
DE C6 27 01 00 05 43 00 14 01 34 B8 62
DE C6 28 01 00 05 43 00 15 01 3C A4 66
DE C6 28 01 00 05 43 00 1F 00 99 1D CD
DE C6 2B 01 00 04 40 A0 18 0C 4F DB
DE C6 2B 01 00 04 40 A0 22 0C 63 E5
DE C6 2C 01 00 04 40 A0 19 0D 44 D8
DE C6 2D 01 00 05 43 00 1A 01 3E 00 77
DE C6 2E 01 00 05 43 00 1B 01 41 F7 77
DE C6 2F 01 00 05 43 00 1C 01 42 1D 7F
DE C6 30 01 00 05 43 00 1D 00 02 CD 3B
DE C6 31 01 00 03 44 04 1E 70 40
DE C6 32 01 00 04 40 A0 1F 03 76 DA
DE C6 35 01 00 05 43 00 22 00 05 26 4D
DE C6 36 01 00 05 43 00 23 00 06 19 4A
DE C6 37 01 00 05 43 00 24 00 07 37 51
DE C6 3A 01 00 05 43 00 27 00 0C 58 5A
DE C6 3B 01 00 04 40 A0 28 03 E6 F0
DE C6 3C 01 00 04 40 A0 29 0C E2 F9
DE C6 3D 01 00 04 40 A0 2A 0D 06 00
DE C6 3E 01 00 05 43 00 2B 00 0D 88 63
DE C6 41 01 00 05 43 00 2E 00 10 B7 6C
DE C6 42 01 00 05 43 00 2F 00 11 BC 6F
DE C6 43 01 00 04 40 A0 30 03 38 02
DE C6 44 01 00 04 40 A0 31 0C 37 0B
DE C6 46 01 00 05 43 00 33 00 14 EE 7A
DE C6 47 01 00 05 43 00 34 00 15 03 7C
DE C6 48 01 00 05 43 00 35 00 17 09 80
DE C6 49 01 00 03 44 04 36 2F 71
DE C6 4A 01 00 05 43 00 37 00 1B 25 88
DE C6 4B 01 00 05 43 00 38 00 1D 3B 8C
DE C6 50 01 00 05 43 00 3D 00 20 72 9B
DE C6 51 01 00 05 43 00 3E 00 22 88 9F
DE C6 52 01 00 05 43 00 3F 00 23 8D A0
DE C6 53 01 00 05 43 00 40 00 24 A2 A5
DE C6 54 01 00 05 43 00 41 00 26 A8 A9
DE C6 55 01 00 04 40 A0 42 03 EB 26
DE C6 56 01 00 04 40 A0 43 0C EA 2E
DE C6 59 01 00 05 43 00 46 00 2C FA BA
DE C6 5A 01 00 05 43 00 47 00 2D F0 B9
DE C6 5F 01 00 04 40 A0 4C 0D 4E 42
DE C6 60 01 00 05 43 00 4D 00 32 4E CE
DE C6 61 01 00 05 43 00 4E 00 37 59 D5
DE C6 62 01 00 05 43 00 4F 00 39 6D DB
DE C6 63 01 00 05 43 00 50 00 3A 73 DA
DE C6 64 01 00 05 43 00 51 00 3C 8A E0
DE C6 65 01 00 05 43 00 52 00 40 92 E4
DE C6 66 01 00 04 40 A0 53 03 8C 46
DE C6 67 01 00 04 40 A0 54 0C 9D 51
DE C6 68 01 00 04 40 A0 55 0D AA 54
DE C6 69 01 00 05 43 00 56 00 45 C7 F3`

Comment: Here is another set of data starting from the beginning. Maybe it's easier to find the pattern.

Comment: Here is another set of data starting from the beginning. 
<code>DE  C6  00  00  00  04  00  00  00  00  C4  A8

DE  C6  01  01  00  0F  00  20  00  01  01  01  02  00  00  01  01  00  00  01  00  41  E6
DE  C6  02  01  00  03  40  20  02  27  0B  
DE  C6  03  01  00  03  40  C0  03  85  B0
DE  C6  04  01  00  03  40  C1  04  79  B1
DE  C6  05  01  00  34  02  82  01  01  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  4E  68 
</code>

Comment: Here is the link to the document in the dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhbh5qyqskq4rmm/checksum%20sample%20data.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Are there any bytes on the wire?  So for example, is there a length byte transmitted?  I have some ideas.